# parse a String inside object

Tags: powershell

```
$GroupMembersCount = $null
$GroupMembersCount = gam print groups domain <domain> members managers owners | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object { [int]$_.ManagersCount -eq 0 -and [int]$_.OwnersCount -eq 0 -and [int]$_.MembersCount -le 3 }
```

This gives me an object one object member is group members and that is a string with spaces like `EmailAddress EmailAddress2 EmailAddress3` and so on.

**One Group email can have many members.**

```
$Results = $null
$Results = $GroupMembersCount | ForEach-Object {
   [PSCustomObject]@{
       GroupEmail = $_.Email
       members = $_.members    #THIS IS THE STING WITH 1 OR MORE MEMBERS WITH A SPACE
   }
}
```

I have tried to nest a `foreach` and the string didn't parse.

I have tried to `replace` the space with a comma and I have tried to convert the string both with the same error as below

```
$GroupMembersCount.members = $GroupMembersCount.members | ConvertFrom-String

The property 'members' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

How do I parse that string and not lose the group email address the members belong to ?

Comment: You just want a list of individual members from the existing string? `members = -split $_.members` should do

Comment: I'm guessing this report is coming from `Get-ADGroup` + `Get-ADGroupMember`, if that's the case and you're looking for the output I posted in question, you should take a step back and, instead of updating the exported data, update your script generating this export.

Comment: It is coming from Google and it is telling me all the Google groups plus counts, member information and role level of each member. 
Your answer worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is safe to split by `\s` (*any whitespace character*), this should generate the export you're looking for:

```
$Results = $GroupMembersCount | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($member in $_.members -split '\s') {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            GroupEmail = $_.Email
            Members = $member
        }
    }
}
```